# CSS display:table

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I am trying out the CSS `display:table` property on some divs, but I am having problems. Below is the code snippet for my test:

```
<div id="table">
<div class="table-row">
    <div class="table-cell">
    <img src="" width="70px" height="70px" />
    </div>
    <div class="table-cell">
    <h1>TEST</h1>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="table-row">
    <div class="table-cell">
    <form>
    <input type="text"></input>

    </div>
    <div class="table-cell">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"></input>
    </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

with the following CSS:

```
#table{
display:table;
}
.table-row{
display:table-row;
}
.table-cell{
display:table-cell;
}
```

The desired result can be seen in the image below:

[image]

Comment: FYI: `display: table` is not new to CSS3. It's part of the stable CSS2.1 spec, and has been for quite some time.

Comment: Oh, ok! I am missinformed then.

Comment: Why do you want to replace `table` by `div#table` ?
Why should some one build a table and not use `<table>`?

Comment: Are you sure that display:table for divs is not new for css3? I was told that you could make elements behave as tables in css3.

Comment: @James Ford: Yes, it's not new. Here's the CSS2 spec for table displays: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html

Comment: @Ghommey: Does that look like an actual table to you?

Comment: @BoltClock this is what I am talking about. I am applying display:table property to div elements?

Comment: What was new was the support of the value `table` in IE8+. See PPK: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/display.html

Comment: @jantimon while the code above looks as if it semantically should be coded as a table, I can encountered edge cases where ul>li lists required table and table-cell properties. This was needed to remove white space issues between <li> tags and we had no control of the markup.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Your desired result doesn't look like a normal table layout. The widths of the columns in the first row are not the same as the width of the columns in the second row.
- You are trying to open a form tag inside one element and close it in another.

Replacing your markup with an actual table doesn't give your desired result, and `display:table` doesn't work any differently.

http://jsfiddle.net/veYTv/1/

Comment: OK Good Guy Greg, so is floats the only solution if I want to make that structure with divs? And the form tag was just a miss

Comment: Yeah, I'd use float, although rarely in this business is anything the *only* solution. :)

Answer (score 3):

You dont need floats divs or tables to achieve your desired result.

Something as simple as http://jsfiddle.net/veYTv/2/ achieves your desired look (note: i havnt extensivly checked this cross browser, it may need minor css tweaks)

```
<h1><img src="" width="70px" height="70px" />TEST</h1>
<input type="text"></input>
<input type="submit" value="Submit"></input>
```

Answer (score 0):

Work! nested tables:

CSS

```
#table{ display:table;}
.table-row{ display:table-row;}
.table-cell{ display:table-cell;}
.table-row_1{ display:table;}
```

HTML

```
<div id="table">
        <div class="table-row_1">
           <div class="table-cell"> <img src="" height="70px" width="70px">
            </div>
          <div class="table-cell">
           <h1>TEST</h1>
         </div>
       </div>
        <div class="table-row">
         <div class="table-cell">
           <form> <input type="text"> </form>
         </div>
         <div class="table-cell"> <input value="Submit" type="submit"> </div>
       </div>
     </div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/antoniodl/mF3PU/2/ 
Bye

Comment: Yikes.  At this point you might as well be doing nested table tags.